# skipped when looking for precompiled header

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

So some reason, my .cpp file is missing it's header file. But I am not including the header file anywhere else. I just started so I checked all the files I made

### enginuity.h

```
#ifndef _ENGINE_
#define _ENGINE_

class Enginuity
{

public:
    void InitWindow();

};
```

### enginuity.cpp

```
#include "Enginuity.h"


void Enginuity::InitWindow()
{

}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "GameProject1.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{

code.....
#endif
```

dont know what's going on. The error I get is

```
1>c:\users\numerical25\desktop\intro todirectx\gameproject\gameproject1\gameproject1\enginuity.cpp(1) : warning C4627: '#include "Enginuity.h"': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
1>        Add directive to 'stdafx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
1>c:\users\numerical25\desktop\intro todirectx\gameproject\gameproject1\gameproject1\enginuity.cpp(8) : fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source?
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Did you read the error message?

> fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source?

I don't see an `#include "stdafx.h"` in enginuity.cpp. ;) If you're using precompiled headers, you need to include the precompiled header in *every* source (.cpp) file.

Comment: Makes me miss being a teaching assistant. "I'm getting the error 'unexpected end of line; possible missing semicolon', what should I do?" "Well...are you missing a semicolon?" "Oh yeah!"

Comment: I tried to add it in my header but I I still got the error. I didn't know it had to be in the .cpp file or even all .cpp files at that. I am getting confused about pre compiled headers. I thought that once a header is included in a file once. It can no longer included again???

Comment: @num It can be, although you usually don't want it to be. It's not included in `enginuity.cpp` though, just `main.cpp`

Comment: Ok, so what about the pragma once. I thought that when that is implemented in a header, the header is only included the first time it's called ?? If I put stdafx.h in all my .cpp files. Wouldnt stdafx.h be ignored by all other files except for the first one that calls it??

Comment: The #include "stdafx.h" needs to be the very first thing in every .cpp file.

Comment: @num No, you can (and must) include it in every cpp file. The only thing `#pragma once` or header guards do is stop you from including a header twice in the same cpp file

Answer (score 22):

I just experienced this error when including stdafx.h in a cpp file located in a parent folder above where stdafx.h is.

```
#include "subfolder\stdafx.h"
```

causes the compile error.
Changing it to:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

fixes the compile error, but then intellisense freaks out.

The "fix" for intellisense, according to someone at Microsoft [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcprerelease/thread/efdf4ae8-437d-4a7f-8cf5-b895257da2bd), is to add "$(ProjectDir)" (or wherever the stdafx.h is) to the list of directories under Project->Properties->Configuration Propertes->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories.

I've verified this works in Visual Studio 2012. Should work in 2010 as well.

Comment: Also works with Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition :)

Comment: Still necessary in Visual Studio 2017 when the .cpp files are in subdirectories.  Thanks for posting this answer!

Answer (score 6):

You'll either want to put the line

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

at the top of all your .cpp files (in this case, enenuity.cpp is the only one missing it.

or disable precompiled headers in your project.

If you have precompiled headers enabled in your project, Visual C++ will look for that `#include` directive at the top of all your source files.  If it's not there, you'll get the negative commentary you received.

Comment: Great, this solved a similar problem that I had, but the error that I was getting was for <string> and <iostream>

Answer (score 5):

IF APPROVED SOLUTION DOES NOT WORK FOR YOU:

In my case the stdafx.h include was after other includes in my .cpp file.

Setting the #include "stdafx.h" statement at the TOP of the .cpp file fixed my errors.

Answer (score 3):

Your header file, `enginuity.h` is missing a `#endif`, or is there a mistake in the posting?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to disable precompiled headers for a single file (VS2010). Select the .cc or .cpp file that is causing the annoyance, right mouse menu, properties, precompiled headers ,
Precompiled Header (change to) Not Using Precompiled Headers.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding #include "stdafx.h" to each .cpp file, you can use the Forced Include File feature. The feature is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ztk84.aspx.

In my case, I was trying to compile existing .cpp files from another project in a new project. I knew that I shouldn't have to change each file because the original project had precompiled headers enabled and it was somehow compiling the same files successfully. I discovered that this option was configured in the original project, and the error went away after I made the same configuration in the new project.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was resolved when i mentioned #include "stdafx.h" on the top of all includes.

Answer (score 0):

Add #include "stdafx.h" to the top of enginuity.cpp or disable precompiled headers in your project.

Answer (score 0):

This error will occur if you have two solutions in a subdirectory of a project and precompiled headers are enabled.  I have experienced the same problem and Microsoft has not fixed it yet.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/552449/

The microsoft work around sometimes works.

Answer (score 0):

As Viktor noted above including stdafx.h *after* other includes will also cause this error and can happen quite easily if you use the Add Function Wizard.  In my case, the wizard added the #include to the trop of the cpp file (despite that it was already included) so I ended up with (using this example)

```
#include "Enginuity.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
// ... other includes ...
#include "Enginuity.h"
```