# #include skipped when looking for precompiled header use -- unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have some code but it wan't compile. I can't go further with this example because this error raises every time I try to debug. 
Note: I am Java programmer, and this message in VS is strange and I coudn't find what is problem. Can someone explain me what this error mean?

Here is code:

zadatak.cpp:

```
// zadatak.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "String.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    String s1(20),s2(20);
    cout<<"Unesi prvi string."<<endl;
    cin>>s1;
    cout<<"Unesi drugi string."<<endl;
    cin>>s2;
    ++s1;
    s2++;
    String s3(40);
    s3=s1+s2;
    cout<<"Treci string: "<<s3<<endl;
}
```

String.cpp:

```
#include "String.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string.h>

String::String(void)
:duzina(0)
{
    niz=new char[duzina];
}

String::String(int br)
:duzina(br)
{
    this->niz=new char[duzina];
}

String::~String(void)
{
    delete [] niz;
}

String::String(String& s)
:duzina(s.duzina)
{
    this->niz=new char[this->duzina];
    for(int i=0; i<this->duzina; i++)
        this->niz[i]=s.niz[i];
}

void String::nadjiPocetak(char rec[])
{
    int poc=0;
    for(int i=0; i<this->duzina; i++)
    {
        int duz=0;
        if(this->niz[i]==rec[0])
        {
            int l=strlen(rec);
            for(int j=0; j<l; j++)
                if(this->niz[i+j]==rec[j])
                    duz+=1;
        }
        if(duz==strlen(rec))
            poc=i;
    }
    if(poc==0)
        cout<<"U stringu ne postoji zadati string."<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"Pocetak je na poziciji: "<<poc+1<<endl;
}

/*void String::ucitaj()
{
    cout<<"Unesi string"<<endl;
    cin>>this->niz;
}

void String::prikazi()
{
    cout<<"String: "<<this->niz<<endl;
}*/

String& String::operator+ (String s)
{
    String *s1;
    s1=new String(duzina+s.duzina);
    strcpy(s1->niz,niz);
    strcat(s1->niz,s.niz);
    return *s1;
}

String& String::operator++ ()
{
    if(niz[0]>='a' && niz[0]<='z')
        niz[0]='A'+niz[0]-'a';
    return *this;
}

String& String::operator++ (int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<duzina; i++)
        if(niz[i]>='a' && niz[i]<='z')
            niz[i]='A'+niz[i]-'a';
    return *this;
}

String& String::operator= (String& s)
{
    duzina=s.duzina;
    delete [] niz;
    niz=new char[duzina];
    strcpy(niz,s.niz);
    return *this;
}

istream& operator>> (istream& in, String& s)
{
    in>>s.niz;
    return in;
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, String& s)
{
    out<<s.niz;
    return out;
}
```

String.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class String
{
private:
    int duzina;
    char* niz;
public:
    String(void);
    String(int br);
    ~String(void);
    String(String& s);
    int vratiDuzinu() {return this->duzina;}
    void nadjiPocetak(char rec[]);
    //void ucitaj();
    //void prikazi();
    String& operator+ (String s);
    String& operator++ ();
    String& operator++ (int n);
    String& operator= (String& s);
    friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, String& s);
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, String& s);
};
```

Error that Visual Studio gives in output is:

> 1>------ Build started: Project: zadatak, Configuration: Debug Win32------
>   1>Build started 12/13/2011 02:44:50 AM.
>   1>InitializeBuildStatus:
>   1>  Touching "Debug\zadatak.unsuccessfulbuild".
>   1>ClCompile:
>   1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
>   1>  zadatak.cpp
>   1>  String.cpp
>   1>c:\users\ivo\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\zadatak\zadatak\string.cpp(1): warning C4627: '#include "String.h"': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
>   1>       Add directive to 'StdAfx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
>   1>c:\users\ivo\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\zadatak\zadatak\string.cpp(2): warning C4627: '#include ': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
>   1>       Add directive to 'StdAfx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
>   1>c:\users\ivo\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\zadatak\zadatak\string.cpp(4): warning C4627: '#include ': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
>   1>       Add directive to 'StdAfx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
>   1>c:\users\ivo\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\zadatak\zadatak\string.cpp(108): fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "StdAfx.h"' to your source?
>   1>  Generating Code...
>   1>
>   1>Build FAILED.
>   1>
>   1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.41
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: i tried this with GCC and it compiled fine, I  just changed the string.h file adding  ,#ifndef STRING_H,#define STRING_H ,#endif

Comment: possible duplicate of [skipped when looking for precompiled header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945980/skipped-when-looking-for-precompiled-header)

Comment: For my particular case, I simply had to move the header file in question to the end of the includes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

in your String.cpp file, as with all .cpp files.

Answer (score 14):

You using the default MSVC project which includes [precompiled headers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/01/26/precompiled-header-files-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx). I would recommend selecting "Dont use precompiled headers option" when you make a project.

Answer (score 13):

You should add

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

in your String.cpp file, but if you used precompiled headers you have to put it on the TOP, such as this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "String.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string.h>
```

There is extensive discussion  [here](https://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/606413) why precompiled headers must come first.

Everything before the PCH is ignored by the compiler, **therefore PCH must come first.**

Answer (score 1):

VS 2013 > Alt+F7  > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > All Options > clean option in "SDL checks" > Apply > OK.