# Why is it an error to define a type before the stdafx.h header in Microsoft Visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++

As a simple example:

```
struct Month
{
  int day;
};

#include "stdafx.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  Month a;
  a.day = 5;
  return 0;
}
```

Attempting to compile this in VS2008, VS2010 or VS2012 results in a C2065 (undeclared identifier error).  Why?

Comment: See also [skipped when looking for precompiled header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945980/skipped-when-looking-for-precompiled-header). The compile warns about stray `#include` directives but doesn't warn about direct declarations. If you want to declare things before your main header, you need to uncheck "Create a precompiled header."

Comment: Thanks.  I had hit the "skipped when looking for" error before, but didn't know there were semantics associated with the the position of the stdafx header.  Thanks again.

Comment: If there were no adverse consequences, why would the compiler bother generating a warning message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Visual C++ will not compile anything prior to the `#include "stdafx.h"` in the source file; it assumes all code in the source up to and including that line is already compiled.

The [wikipedia page for precompiled headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header) states this and it's confirmed on [Microsoft's own pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/z0atkd6c.aspx):

> The compiler treats all code occurring before the `.h` file as precompiled. It skips to just beyond the `#include` directive associated with the `.h` file, uses the code contained in the `.pch` file, and then compiles all code after filename.

What's *probably* happening under the covers is that the *creation* of a pre-compiled header file (`.pch`) involves the storage of state at that point. Then, when you *include* the header, it just loads up that state as-is (overwriting the current state) and everything that has been compiled in the source file before that `#include` line is effectively thrown away.

Comment: Thank you for your fast and accurate answer.

Comment: You can, of course, "fix" this by turning off precompiled headers for your project. If you're just dealing with a trivial project, you probably aren't benefiting much from precompiled headers anyway.